# Patterns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, design-patterns

This is in python language.
I need to print this pattern, depending on the number of lines a user enters:

'##'
'# #'

The next pattern is three spaces away and so on...

This is my code but it prints the second number sign on a different line.  I need them to go on the same line.

```
 def drawPatternIII (lines):
   for i in range(lines):
      for j in range(1):
          print('#')
      for j in range(i+1):
          print (' ', end = '')
      print ('#')
```

please help!

Comment: the first print outputs a newline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add `end=""` to the first `print()` call.  While you are at it, remove the pointless for loop with a single iteration.

A concise alternative would be

```
for i in range(lines):
    print("#" + " "*i + "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

The one liner version!

```
def drawPatternIII (lines):
     list(map(print,["#" + " "*i + "#" for i in range(lines)]))
```